# Mouse Scrolling in Windows' Sticky Notes

Tags: windows, mouse, mousewheel, sticky

I like using Windows' Sticky Notes to keep a handy list of tasks that I'm working on, which can get a little lengthy at times. It works nicely, except for scrolling. Is there a way to use the mouse-wheel to scroll within a Sticky Note instead of clicking & dragging the scroll-bar?

Comment: Why the negative votes? If you're going to down-vote a question, please comment the reason why.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found that if I:

1. Select the Sticky note with mouse
2. Press the Alt key 2 times

RESULT:
mouse scroll will be enabled

Thanks for the post, after 7 months of loving, using Stickies this drove me crazy!

Happy computing ~

Comment: How in the world did you discover this?? Totally works tho except I only need one keypress

Comment: like user3897493 said, this is only temporary...wizmouse works nicely

Comment: bruuuuuh This works!

Comment: Thanks!! hauhauhau

Comment: What the heck ?

Comment: Just Perfect answer. Works for me on Windows 10. Kudos for sharing the trick. ***1 Alt*** works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Pressing the alt key twice works, but only temporarily. A free program called WizMouse takes care of the program completely.

Answer (score 1):

One (very unsatisfying) way to scroll with the mousewheel is to select the "menu" by pressing ALT (or clicking on the '+' in the top left and releasing the mousebutton elsewhere), THEN mousewheeling. But even so, it scrolls page by page which is not very usual...

Comment: I agree that it's not ideal, but it works - thank you!

Answer (score -1):

set the keyboard command in the settings for the application

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't see any settings for the Sticky Notes in Windows 7.